# PHP SQL Select row between dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, date

I am trying to create a reservation system and want to check if a reservation has already been made between two dates. However, my SQL always returns false.

```
$reservation_date_start = date('y-m-d', strtotime($fields['reservation_date_start']));
$reservation_date_end = date('y-m-d', strtotime($fields['reservation_date_end']));

// Save data to database
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'mb_bookings';

$date_exists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name 
WHERE (reservation_date_start >= $reservation_date_start AND reservation_date_start < $reservation_date_end ) 
OR (reservation_date_end >= $reservation_date_start AND reservation_date_end < $reservation_date_end) 
AND (accommodation_id = $accommodation_id)"
);
```

I've already tried using the `BETWEEN` function, but also without any success.

The dates are correct in the database (y-m-d)

Db example:

[image]

Any help would really be appreciated, as I've been struggling with it for days now...

Comment: what is the error you get? where (a>b) or (b>a) should be  where ( (a>b) or (b>a) ) with the extra parenthesis

Comment: What is the datatype of columns `reservation_date_start` and `reservation_date_end`?

Comment: @Alex7 The problem i'm getting is that the query always returns 0. I've tried to add the extra parenthesis, but still no success.

Comment: @AshwaniGoyal The datatype is Date. `code`reservation_date_start date NOT NULL`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date format `y-m-d` gives 16-04-01. Change it to `Y-m-d` to get 2016-04-01. Query should work then.

If I understand your need correctly you want to check if two periods overlap. I think this should do it (mark added parnetheses and apostrophes):

```
SELECT *
FROM $table_name 
WHERE 
(
    (
     STR_TO_DATE('$reservation_date_start', '%Y-%m-%d') <= reservation_date_end
     AND
     STR_TO_DATE('$reservation_date_end', '%Y-%m-%d') > reservation_date_start
    )
OR
    (
     STR_TO_DATE('$reservation_date_end', '%Y-%m-%d') >= reservation_date_start
     AND
     STR_TO_DATE('$reservation_date_start', '%Y-%m-%d') < reservation_date_end
    )
)
AND (accommodation_id = $accommodation_id)
```

**EDIT**

Simplified condition for overlapping:

```
SELECT *
FROM $table_name 
WHERE 
        STR_TO_DATE('$reservation_date_end', '%Y-%m-%d') >= reservation_date_start
    AND STR_TO_DATE('$reservation_date_start', '%Y-%m-%d') <= reservation_date_end
    AND accommodation_id = $accommodation_id
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not had any effect. The $date_exists query still returns 0.

Comment: Really many many many thanks! You're solution is finally working! As I'm trying to understand your solution, does this mean that mySQL can't read any PHP Date values? And therefor it needs to have the STR_TO_DATE function?

Comment: @Thjeu I don't know. I'm not really mySQL user so I've added STR_TO_DATE just in case. In PostgreSQL it would work just with string `'2016-04-01'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$reservation_date_start = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($fields['reservation_date_start']));
$reservation_date_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fields['reservation_date_end']));
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not had any effect. The $date_exists query still returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM $table_name 
WHERE date_filed BETWEEN reservation_date_start AND $reservation_date_end;

Comment: I do not understand you're solution, so please correct me if i'm wrong. But there is no column called 'date_filed', so i do not see how this would work.